# Regarding deleting first 327 lines in all the .dat files in a folder

Tags: text-processing

In a folder, I have number of files that are in .dat extension format (it is originally .xvg format but have changed to .dat format to plot all other graphs in a single plot) which contains the values along with the some written headings etc., as :

```
 # Grace project file

#

@version 50125
@page size 792, 612

@page scroll 5%

@page inout 5%

@link page off

@map font 8 to "Courier", "Courier"

@map font 10 to "Courier-Bold", "Courier-Bold"

@map font 11 to "Courier-BoldOblique", "Courier-BoldOblique"

@map font 9 to "Courier-Oblique", "Courier-Oblique"

@map font 4 to "Helvetica", "Helvetica"

@map font 6 to "Helvetica-Bold", "Helvetica-Bold"

@map font 7 to "Helvetica-BoldOblique", "Helvetica-BoldOblique"

@map font 5 to "Helvetica-Oblique", "Helvetica-Oblique"

.

.

.

.

@    s0 errorbar riser linestyle 1

@    s0 errorbar riser clip off

@    s0 errorbar riser clip length 0.100000

@    s0 comment "rdf_CaNm.xvg"

@    s0 legend  "N1"

@target G0.S0

@type xy

0 0

0.002 0

0.004 0
```

ie., there are 327 lines  from #Grace project file(being line one) --> @type xy(being line 327) and then the 0 0 is the 328th line, 0.002 0 is the 329th line etc.

How can I delete all the first 327 lines in all the files of .dat format containing in the folder (yes all those .dat files have first 327 lines as stated above) through the command in terminal?

Comment: with the simple addition of `sed ... *.dat`

Answer (score 1):

To delete a number of lines from one file, you will do:

```
sed -i -e 1,327d file.dat
```

Here you do it with `--in-place` (-i) which is *change the file*, and `1,327d` means delete from line one to 327.

To delete the first 327 lines from all files name `*.dat` in this directory and below, use `find`:

```
find -name '*.dat' -exec sed -i -e 1,327d {} \;
```

Comment: or, if there are not millions of such files, `sed -i -e 1,327d *.dat`

Comment: add the regular-file clause in `find` to make it more accurate and `sed` can handle more than one file:   `find . -type f -name \*.dat -exec sed -si -e 1,327d {} +`